# Regex not working in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have this regex for now 
It should catch something like this

**org.package;version="[1.0.41, 1.0.51)"** and "," optionally if it is not last element. 
Also if after package i added .* because the package could be "org.package.util.something" until ";version"

I tried it online in Regex tool and it is working like this

**org.package(.*.*)?;version="[[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9],\s[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9])",?**

but i dont know what should i change so it can work in bash

`package="org.package"
sed -i "s/"$$package.*;version="\[[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9],[[:space:]][0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]\)",?"//g" "$file"`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/UnB1zq

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? To find and output the version or to replace it?

Comment: If i have org.package;version="[1.0.41m 1.0.5 the other digit could be on the next row and even trying only this example to add [[:space:]]* between 5 and 1 it doesnt work

Comment: The goal is to replace the whole string with empty string or just remove it i.e org.package;version="[1.041, 1.051]"

Comment: @КалоянНиков "the next row"? `sed` doesn't check/match more than one row at once.
You could try workarounds like using the `tr` command to first replace all `\n` line endings with `\r`, then do sed, and then replace `\r` back to `\n`

Comment: general note: you also might want to replace `[0-9]` and `[0-9][0-9]` with `[0-9]+` or `\d+` in order to not make an assumption about how many digits each number has.

Comment: i replace "\r\n" (because i saw line endings are CR LF ) with '#' and it appends 2 # after that i cant reset it

Comment: How can i add matching group for the other characters currently i`m trying this after the last character of the package in the Regex i add ([0-9a-z\.#\s]*)* but it only matches alphabetical if they dont have spaces , # or digits. i.e i want to catch org.package.http11 or org.package.http # .something or org.package.http.s #omething

Answer (score 0):

Change the double quotes arround sed command by single quotes, because variable  expansion of `$package` single quotes are closed and double quotes are use arround variable

```
package="org.package"
sed -i 's/'"$package"'.*;version="\[[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9],[[:space:]][0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]\)",?//g' "$file"
```

before using command with `-i` option check the output is correct

Comment: Thanks for that and something other - if i want to check for 0 or more spaces before every character i need to add [[;space:]]* before every single char ?

Comment: @КалоянНиков: Yes, but you should add `[[:space:]]*`.

Comment: I tried this but it become ugly and says unmatched sed: -e expression #1, char 435: Unmatched ) or \):                                                   
`[[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*v[[:space:]]*e[[:space:]]*r[[:space:]]*s[[:space:]]*i[[:space:]]*o[[:space:]]*n[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*\[[[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*.[[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*.[[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*.[[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*.[0-9][[:space:]]*[0-9][[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*,?//g' "file"`

Comment: it's ugly and will not be efficient because for example `[[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]*`, can match everything different ways, the error is because closing parenthese `)` must not be escaped to match a literal `)` except when `-r` option

Comment: If it is possible for this to be added ([a-z]*\.*\s*) *